# Error While starting the wso2 server in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wso2, esb

While starting wso2 server, server is not getting started and showing some errors

//
**Repository Failed to add new Collection /_system/governanceThere already exist non collection resource.**

**[2017-12-01 12:41:16,151] [EI-Core] ERROR - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Failed to activate Registry Core bundle**

**org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Failed to add new Collection /_system/governanceThere already exist non collection resource.**

at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.addEmptyCollection(Repository.java:1148)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.add(Repository.java:1013)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Repository.put(Repository.java:305)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.put(EmbeddedRegistry.java:709)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.put(CacheBackedRegistry.java:591)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.addBaseCollectionStructure(RegistryUtils.java:779)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.addSystemCollections(UserRegistry.java:357)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.init(UserRegistry.java:331)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.access$100(UserRegistry.java:61)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry$2.run(UserRegistry.java:249)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.(UserRegistry.java:246)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.(UserRegistry.java:225)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getUserRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:427)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getSystemRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:292)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getSystemRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:276)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.getSystemRegistry(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:262)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:598)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:520)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:69)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2017-12-01 12:41:16,215] [EI-Core]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
[2017-12-01 12:41:40,332] [EI-Core]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined

Comment: Is this a fresh pack or have you made any changes?

Comment: @Bee, I made some changes to my axis2.xml & axis2_blocking_client.xml, which worked. When I started the server next day, it started throwing error.

Comment: HI @ManojKumar
I have faced the same issue in integrator.bat file, it is not fresh package. already used.did u get any solution for this?